# How to delete ==%0A from url in order to obfuscate the ids of my records in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

using the built-in OpenSSL library to encrypt and decrypt the id

the url be like this: http://localhost:3000/requests/Ym7c8FQQlCe5FvotzKu4yw==%0A
and i want to delete ==%0A from it ? how ?

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

module Obfuscate
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend self
  end

  def cipher
    OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
  end

  def cipher_key
    'blah!'
  end

  def decrypt(value)
    c = cipher.decrypt
    c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(cipher_key)
    c.update(Base64.decode64(value.to_s)) + c.final
  end

  def encrypt(value)
    c = cipher.encrypt
    c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(cipher_key)
    Base64.encode64(c.update(value.to_s) + c.final)
  end
end
```

and in my model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Obfuscate

  def to_param
    encrypt id
  end
end
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but why would you encrypt the ids?

Comment: Use a GUID instead of encryption unless you have a specific need to generate new versions of encrypted IDs.

Comment: for some reasons i want to hide the id of my records in db from url

Comment: Cool. And if you could explain WHY you want to hide them that would help a lot. It's an uncommon thing to do and can't see any real reason why anyone would to it like that.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [activeuuid](https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid)

When you create a Create a Migration this is how it should look like

```
class CreateEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users, :id => false  do |t|
      t.uuid :id, :primary_key => true
      t.uuid :something_id  # belongs_to :something

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :emails, :id
  end
end
```

then in your models all you have to do is include  `include ActiveUUID::UUID`

and this is a example of a uuid `1dd74dd0-d116-11e0-99c7-5ac5d975667e`

I hope that this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use [Friendly ID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). Basically, it replaces the `id` in your routes with a `name` or other field. It changes

```
/requests/Ym7c8FQQlCe5FvotzKu4yw==%0A
```

to

```
/requests/some_cool_name_in_your_database
```

That way, your users don't see the `id`, but instead see something a little more pretty. And if your users were to return to that page, it would still work because you have a valid "id".